# Declaration of 1D array with nonlinear functionality between boundaries

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Arrays_0

Implicit none

Integer :: i , Read_number , Vig_Position , Vipg_Position , n_iter
Integer , parameter :: Br_gra = 12
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_gra ) :: Vig = [ ( i , i = 1 , Br_gra) ]
Integer , parameter , dimension ( Br_gra ) :: Vipg = [ 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 7 , 7 , 7 ]
Integer :: Result_of_calculation

Write(*,*)"Enter the number (From 1 to Br_gra):"
Read(*,*) Read_number

Vig_Position = Vig(Read_number)
Vipg_Position = Vipg(Vig_Position)

!K_str( Vig_Position_temp ) = Vig_Position_temp + 2.3

   n_iter = 0

   Result_of_calculation = Vig_Position

   Do while( Vipg_Position .ne. Vipg(1) )

      n_iter = n_iter + 1

      Vig_Position = Vipg_Position

     ! K_str( Vig_Position_temp ) = Vig_Position_temp + 2.3

      Result_of_calculation = Result_of_calculation + Vig_Position

      Vipg_Position = Vipg(Vig_Position)

   End Do

Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"The number of iteration is:",n_iter
Write(*,'(a,1x,i0)')"The result of calculation is:",Result_of_calculation

End Program Arrays_0
```

There is no problem with code if I want to make calculation for a `n_iter` and `Result_of_calculation` but I have a problem with declaration of `K_str` in way that can follow correctly specific use of this two variables (my intention for using this variables in calculation was showed in comments).

So question is how to declare, for example, in case that `Read_number` is 12?
In that case I have: `K_str(12), K_str(7), K_str(3) and K_str(1)`.

What I can do is this:

```
Real, dimension (Br_gra):: K_str
```

But in this case a must import one more loop for all elements from `Vig` (12 calculation). I want to prevent that number of calculation and in this case, I want to that my code make just a 4 calculation.

How to do that?

Comment: Could you comment on what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: I need to calculate value of  `K_str` for every single Iteration.

Comment: OK. But there is no "_str in the sample. What is the meaning of the computation? I simply don't get what is the purpose of the code.

Comment: `K_str` was in comment in code. I do not want to make this calculation: `(K_str(i) = i + 2.3 , i = 1 , Br_Gra )`.h
I just want to do only for values which are mentioned in explanation.

Comment: OK so why12, 7, 3 and 1? Where did yoi get those numbers? What is the meaning of all of this?

Comment: Start the code, enther a 12 from keyboard and you will get that numberes and for every number i need to calculate something for a `K_str`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157712/discussion-between-judge-dred-and-vladimir-f).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get an array, which e.g. starts at index 1, ends at index 12, but does not contain all the indexes in between, just some of them?

That is not possible with Fortran arrays. Actually, it is not possible with arrays in any other language I know.

One can use the dictionary data structure for something like that, which is intrinsic in some languages, but not Fortran. There are external libraries for similar data-structures in Fortran. See http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Hash+tables

You could also use a linked list with all usual drawbacks and advantages (no direct indexing etc.).

Unless your need is for some very large ranges of indexes, much much larger than your example, use a regular array that contains all indexes.

You can also use one array which will contain the data (indexed 1 to 4) and another array of the same size, which will contain the global position (1,3,7 and 12). Or a derived type with these two components. But it will not be the same usage as you propose.

Comment: That is true. The `Vig` and `Vipg` arrays are definition of tree with branches and nodes. Array `Vig` contains the index for a branches and `Vipg` contains index for a nodes. Using this arrays in code I will always get a shortest road to the routh of tree and for every single branch i need to make calculation for a `К_str` which depends on index of that branch. I now that is possible to make calculation for every single index of branches `( 1 - Br_gra )` but...